# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Everything is normal even in the console, if I delete the image, the other information appears, but when I add an image, it does not recognize it ,
How can I solve this problem

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './SinglePage.css';
import Style from '../../components/styles/Style';
import Logo from '../../components/Logo/Logo';
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar/Navbar';
import RightBar from '../../components/RightBar/RightBar';
import {  useParams } from 'react-router';
import API from '../../api/Api';
import Loading from '../../components/loading/Loading';


const SinglePage = () => {
    const [loading , setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [Data , setData] = useState([]);
    const [message , setMessage] = useState();

    const id = useParams();
    const URL = 'http://localhost:8001/'

    useEffect(() => {
        API.get("api/GetPosts").then((res) => {
            if (res.data.AllData.length === 0) {
              setMessage(true);
            } else {
                const card= res.data.AllData.find(x => x._id === id.id)
              setData(card);
              setLoading(true);
            }
          });
        
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <Logo />
                <Navbar />
                <div style={Style}>
                    <RightBar />
                    <div className="SinglePage-Container">
                        {loading && (
                            <div style={{margin:'0 auto', marginTop:'2rem' , display:'flex' , justifyContent:'center' , alignItems:'center'}}>
                                    <Loading/>
                                </div>
                        )}
                            {message ? (
                                <div style={{margin:'0 auto', marginTop:'2rem' , display:'flex' , justifyContent:'center' , alignItems:'center'}}>
                                    <h1>لا يوجد مقالة في هذا الرابط </h1>
                                </div>
                            ) : (
                                <>
                                <div className="SinglePage-Image">
                                    
                                <img src={`${URL}${Data.images[0].filename}`}  alt=''/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="SinglePage-Title">
                                {Data.title}
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                {Data.article}
                            </p>
                                </>
                            )}
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default SinglePage
```

[image: TypeError]

Comment: Because of useEffect runs after the first render, Data's initial state is to set to an empty array, so it's normal that the first element of data is undefined. So you get this error.

Comment: In addition please edit your post and remove Lorem ipsum things.

Comment: @Deniz how i can solve it

Comment: Do the same as you do with `message`, check that it exists before you render it. So change ```<img src={`${URL}${Data.images[0].filename}`}  alt=''/>``` to ```{ Data.length && <img src={`${URL}${Data.images[0].filename}`}  alt=''/> }```. Also remember to actually add alt text ;)

Comment: @Dominik The problem is solved, but the image does not appear but other data has appered

Comment: What is the shape of your `Data` object?

Comment: @Dominik yes object !!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I gather you get an object back from your API and your default value for `Data` is an array which would then be wrong.

And to make sure you render the image only once the image has been retrieved from the API you can use this:

```
DATA.images && <img src={`${URL}${Data.images[0].filename}`} alt=''/>
```

All together now:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './SinglePage.css';
import Style from '../../components/styles/Style';
import Logo from '../../components/Logo/Logo';
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar/Navbar';
import RightBar from '../../components/RightBar/RightBar';
import {  useParams } from 'react-router';
import API from '../../api/Api';
import Loading from '../../components/loading/Loading';


const SinglePage = () => {
    const [loading , setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [Data , setData] = useState({});
    //                                 ^-- CHANGE
    const [message , setMessage] = useState(false);
    //                                        ^-- CHANGE

    const id = useParams();
    const URL = 'http://localhost:8001/'

    useEffect(() => {
        API.get("api/GetPosts").then((res) => {
            if (res.data.AllData.length === 0) {
                setMessage(true);
            } else {
                const card= res.data.AllData.find(x => x._id === id.id)
                setData(card);
                setLoading(true);
            }
            });
        
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <Logo />
                <Navbar />
                <div style={Style}>
                    <RightBar />
                    <div className="SinglePage-Container">
                        {loading && (
                            <div style={{margin:'0 auto', marginTop:'2rem' , display:'flex' , justifyContent:'center' , alignItems:'center'}}>
                                    <Loading/>
                                </div>
                        )}
                            {message ? (
                                <div style={{margin:'0 auto', marginTop:'2rem' , display:'flex' , justifyContent:'center' , alignItems:'center'}}>
                                    <h1>لا يوجد مقالة في هذا الرابط </h1>
                                </div>
                            ) : (
                                <>
                                <div className="SinglePage-Image">
                                    
                                {
                                    DATA.images && <img src={`${URL}${Data.images[0].filename}`} alt=''/>
                                }
                                {/*  ^--- CHANGE */}
                            </div>
                            <div className="SinglePage-Title">
                                {Data.title}
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                {Data.article}
                            </p>
                                </>
                            )}
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default SinglePage
```